# Why does {0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1...} diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

My book says that this sequence diverges because it "takes on only two values, 0 and 1, and never stays arbitrarily close to either one for n sufficiently large." However, I don't understand why this cannot converge. My intuition says that for an infinite n, we will reach a point where there are infinitely many 0's before hitting a 1, because each repetition, we get more and more zeroes. Eventually, wouldn't we have infinite zeros, and the pattern would converge to 0?

Comment: You can not simply say "an infinite $n$" because, in general, sequences are only defined on finite natural numbers.

Comment: The sequence contains a subsequence which is all $1$'s and another which is all $0$'s, The first subsequence converges to $1$ and the second converges to $0$. If the original sequence were convergent to some limit $L$, then all subsequences must also converge to $L$.

Comment: The average converges to 0.  But the sequence is not its average.

Comment: @NobleMushtak They may be only defined on natural numbers, but we are taking limits of them and seeing what happens with n sufficiently large. If we must deal with natural numbers, I don't see why I can't just claim "for n sufficiently large that is still a finite number but getting closer and closer to infinity"

Comment: So, we claim it does not converge to $0$.  To see if you understand the $\epsilon$-type definition of convergence, try to use it to prove that!

Comment: No matter how large you take $n$, you are still infinitely far from infinity.

Comment: @GEdgar The epsilon-delta proof actually is what did it for me. I may have seemingly infinite 0s at a certain point, but there is eventually a number n where I am required to put a 1, and this is outside the bounds of L+epsilon. Infinity is hard.

Comment: @Bungo Good point. Btw I somewhat understand your subsequence argument but I can't figure how you split a sequence into subsequences accurately. I feel like I wouldn't know where each subsequence should be used in the original sequence, vs using the other subsequence, if that makes any sense.

Comment: @AlexG "Infinty is hard" essentially sums up my experience with real analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Eventually we will have infinite zeros

No, you will not. The number of zeros between each pair of ones gets bigger and bigger, but it is always finite. Consider that each term in the sequence only has a finite number of terms that come before it. So if after some instance of 1, you have infinitely many zeros, how many zeros precede this 1?

Moreover, we have a definition for a real sequence converging:

> A sequence $a_n$ converges to a point $a$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that if $n\geq N$, then $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$.

So if $\epsilon=1/2$, how big must $N$ be?

Comment: I'll accept this in a minute -- need the timer to finish. But this makes sense, along with the other comments here; I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the definition of convergence for a sequence. For any positive $\varepsilon$, you want to find a $M \in \mathbb N$  such that whenever $n \ge M$, then  $\left| x_n \right| < \varepsilon$.
However, for $0 \le \varepsilon < 1$, you wont be able to find such an $M$, since at some point, there will always be $X_n = 1$, even though $n \ge M$

Answer (score 1):

Remember the epsilon-delta definition of the limit. To prove that this converges, you need to give me what the limit is, and the neighborhood of x I can choose from. If I cannot find an x that exceeds your limit, then the sequence is convergent.

So let's say you want to show that the sequence converges to any value less than 1, and the neighborhood I can choose from is a very large number to infinity. No matter how  far we go, there will ALWAYS be a 1 I can choose, which means the limit cannot be less than 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you claim this sequence (call its terms $x_n$) converges to $0$, then you must provide some *finite* $N$ such that $x_n = 0$ for all $n \geq N$. There can be no such $N$, however, since $1$ appears an infinite number of times in the sequence.

Comment: You need that for n>N Xn will be arbitrarily close to zero, not equal zero. 1/n —> 0 but it’s never 0.

Comment: You are correct in general. I was answering under the assumption that, for this example, every term in the sequence is either 0 or 1.

Comment: Ahhh, you are correct then.